# Find embedded resource names in assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-assembly, embedded-resource

In C# or else VB.Net, there is a way to find the embedded resource(s) contained in an assembly?

Because I'm manually extracting an embedded resource form an assembly in this way:

```
    Dim embeddedFileName As String = "MyResources.resx"
    Dim targetFilePath As String = "C:\NewMyResources.resx"
    Using s As Stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(embeddedFileName)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(CInt(s.Length - 1)) {}
        Dim read As Integer = s.Read(buffer, 0, CInt(s.Length))
        Using fs As New FileStream(targetFilePath, FileMode.Create)
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        End Using
    End Using
```

I would like to automate the task in future projects to extract the resource(s) without knowing the exact name(s), it is possible?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the sources of [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)? I think it lists resources embedded into assemblies.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper I've taken a fast look on it but I don't know where to start searching inside, anyways debug and deep into a 3rd party source of +2k CSharp classes only to try to find the solution to a simple question then that is not the idea of what I have to perform a research, but thanks anyways for the suggestion!.

Comment: If you want to manually find it (by poking around), you can open the assembly in `ILDASM` and you will see the resource (with its full name) as an `.mresource public` entry in the `Manifest`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a list of embedded resources with the [Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx) method.